# Entity Framework 6.0 Error With Mysql Connector 6.8.3.0

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

In one of my project i was using entity framework 5.0 with MySql 5.6 With Mysql Connector Version 6.7.4.0.

Previously it was working fine but due to some reason i have to update the entity framework version from 5.0 to 6.0 and for which i have to update the mysql connector version from 6.7.4.0 to 6.8.3.0 which is the recommended mysql connector to use with entity framework 6.x.

Due to which now i am not able to update my .edmx file. while updating it is giving error saying your project reference the latest version of entity framework; however an entity framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection.

Following is the screen shot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EF 6 & EF 5 seem to be not compatible. Try [this (point 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6). Or you could remove your *.edmx file from your project and generate a new one from the database instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with it as wel, I had to use a provider tag in the enitityframework tag in my app.conf

see the link below for more information and follow those steps:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264

look at this one to get a better sence of the code.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html